# ¿Qué es recomendable para tener como Foreign Key en un modelo que tiene una tabla de más de 14mil registros?

Tags: django, sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla de enfermedades que tiene solo 3 columnas:

- El id automático.
- Un código `varchar(10)`.
- El  nombre `string`.

Pero, tiene 14197 registros.

El problema es que su  llave primaria (Primary Key) es llave foránea para otros modelos, pero está demorando mucho en cargarla.

Uso `django` y `PostgreSql`, ¿qué es lo más recomendable para que no se demore tanto la carga de esa `Foreign Key` en el `template`?

[image: template]

## modelos

```py
class Cie10(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    nombre = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return (u"%s (%s)"%(self.nombre, self.codigo)).strip() or "-"

class EnfermedadGeneral(Enfermedad):
    dias = models.IntegerField(validators=[no_negativo])
    cie10 = models.ForeignKey(Cie10, verbose_name="diagnóstico Cie10")
    soportes = models.FileField(upload_to=crear_ruta_archivo_enfermedad_general, blank=True, null=True)

class Enfermedad(models.Model):
    persona = models.ForeignKey(Persona, related_name="enfermo")
    responsable = models.ForeignKey(Persona, related_name="responsable")
    municipio = models.ForeignKey(Municipio)
    zona = models.IntegerField(choices=ZONAS)
    sucursal = models.ForeignKey(Sucursal)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area)
    cargo = models.ForeignKey(Cargo)
    tipo_empleado = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TIPO_EMPLEADO)
    fecha_ingreso = models.DateField()
    fecha_diligenciamiento = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    fecha = models.DateField(verbose_name="fecha del diagnóstico")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (u"%s (%s)"%(self.persona, self.fecha)).strip() or "-"

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("persona", "fecha"),)
```

## Ejemplo de Form

```py
class EnfermedadGeneralForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: model = EnfermedadGeneral
    exclude = ('responsable', 'persona', 'sucursal', 'area', 'cargo', 'tipo_empleado', 'fecha_ingreso', 'fecha_diligenciamiento',)
    widgets = {
        'fecha' : MyDateWidget(),
        'municipio': Select2Widget(),
        'cie10': Select2Widget(),
        'soportes' : MyFileInput(), }
```

## Formulario en el template

```html
<form class="form-vertical" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form layout="horizontal" %}
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" onclick="$('#id_dia_semana').attr('disabled', false);">
        Registrar <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

## Ejemplo de vista

```py
@login_required
@all_permission_required('novedades.add_enfermedadgeneral')
def crear_enfermedad_general(request, idPersona=None):
    persona = None
    hoy = datetime.now()
    usuario = Persona.objects.get(usuario=request.user)

    enfermedadGeneralCreada = request.session.get('nueva_enfermedad_general')

    if enfermedadGeneralCreada == True:
        del request.session['nueva_enfermedad_general']

    if idPersona:
        try:
            persona = Persona.objects.get(id=idPersona)
        except Exception:
            return redirect('crear_enfermedad_general')


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EnfermedadGeneralForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            objeto = form.save(commit=False)
            objeto.responsable = Persona.objects.get(usuario=request.user)
            objeto.persona = persona
            objeto.sucursal = persona.sucursal
            objeto.area = persona.cargo.area
            objeto.cargo = persona.cargo
            objeto.tipo_empleado = persona.tipo_empleado
            objeto.fecha_ingreso = persona.fecha_ingreso

            objeto.soportes = None
            objeto.save()

            try:
                objeto.soportes = request.FILES['soportes']
            except Exception:
                1

            objeto.save()

            request.session['nueva_enfermedad_general'] = True
            return redirect('crear_enfermedad_general')

        form2 = CedulaForm(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            persona = form2.cleaned_data['persona']
            return redirect('crear_enfermedad_general', persona.id)
    else:
        form = EnfermedadGeneralForm()
        try:
            form2 = CedulaForm({'persona': persona.id})
        except Exception:
            form2 = CedulaForm()

    return render(request, 'enfermedad_general.html', {
        'enfermedadGeneralCreada': enfermedadGeneralCreada,
        'persona': persona,
        'form': form,
        'form2': form2,
        'hoy': hoy,
        'usuario': usuario,
    })
```

Comment: Diana, muestra tus modelos, tus vistas, queremos saber como haces los queries. Tal vez asi te podemos ayudar. 14,197 registros son un paseo en el parque para PostgreSQL

Comment: 14,000 registros son muy pocos para cualquier base de datos hoy en día, me parece que tu problema está en otro lado, cuantos registros estas presentando al usuario a la vez?

Comment: @DianaCarolinaHernandez ¡Bienvenida a StackOverflow en español! Por favor, en lugar de poner código en comentarios, edita tu pregunta y pon el código ahí.

Comment: @Barranka editado n. es que apenas me acostumbro

Comment: @CésarBustíos no hago ninguna consulta explícita sólo lo predeterminado de django, me puedes ayudar a corregirlo?

Comment: @BlackTigerX Uno sólo, eso creo... ahí lo puedes ver en la imágen, dónde dice Diagnóstico cie10... yo creo que eso así no más precarga mucho, pero sin ese widget es más lento.

Comment: @DianaCarolinaHernandez al parecer el código que has pegado está incompleto, no veo por ejemplo la clase abstracta `Enfermedad` de la cual estás heredando o el modelo para `Persona`

Comment: Te recomiendo usar la librería select-select2 para hacer un ajax de búsqueda para esos campos, otra opción podría ser que en el forms. Inicialices el queryset de ese campo con algún filtro en caso exista

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No estoy 100% seguro porque el widget `Select2Widget` no lo conozco, pero si es [este](http://django-easy-select2.readthedocs.org/en/latest) estás cargando los 14 mil registros en el renderizado.

Quizás deberías cambiar el widget para te tome uno que haga la búsqueda por AJAX después de N caracteres para:

1. Hacer mas liviano el template
2. No traer los 14mil registros

Puedes usar [esto](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/master/form.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias, yo sospechaba de ese widget pero nunca entendí cómo funcionaba, lo probaré y te respondo.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que no es responsabilidad de la aplicacion la eficiencia de la búsqueda, si no de la base de datos.

Lo mas importante para hacer consulta eficientes/poco costosas en una base de datos es tener en cuenta ciertas cosas:

- **Proyección**: la cantidad de columnas que retorna tu consulta. Es importante por que cada columna demanda X bytes en cada registro del resultado. En tablas gigantes, esto se puede volver un problema.
- **Filtrado**: Debes dejar bien en claro el criterio de selección para devolver la menor cantidad de filas posibles.
- **Pre-compilacion de consulta**: Evita que cada vez que realices una consulta, esta tenga que realizar el plan de consulta continuamente ya que es costoso. Esto se debe a que, por lo general, se realizan las mismas consultas sin variaciones.
- **Plan de consulta**: Revisar el plan de consulta para evitar métodos inadecuados de selección elegidos por el motor de base de datos y especificar la forma de acceso a los datos que quieres. Esto es primordial ya que en grandes conjuntos de datos, los motores tienden a hacer malas elecciones con respecto a esto.

Y hay otros métodos, de igual importancia, cuando las cosas no se solucionan simplemente.

- **Indexacion**: Si no hay indices, el motor de base de datos va a tener la necesidad de buscar en todo el conjunto de registros los resultados deseados. Es importante tener indices para facilitar esa búsqueda como si fuera una guía telefónica. Hay que saber hacer una buena elección entre indices simples y compuestos y entre físicos y lógicos.
- **Estadísticas**: Los motores de base de datos mas avanzados tienen un registro(estadísticas) de los indices más accedidos y tiene espacios virtuales especialmente para acceder mas rápidamente a estos.
- **Particiones**: Una solución para partir la gran cantidad de registros en partes menores según tus criterios. Se usa mucho para evitar consultar indices grandes o acceder a un conjunto de registros mas acodados por criterio dentro de conjunto principal de registros.

Si tus problemas exceden este tipo de cosas, empieza a tener en cuenta temas como cache en memoria.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder determinar si el problema es en la consulta o en otra parte, como parece ser el caso (concretamente, el renderizado del select con 14k entradas), es muy recomendable la extensión [Django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar). Entre otra información útil, te muestra en número de consultas realizadas a la base de datos y el número de milisegundos que le ha llevado ejecutar cada una de ellas.